# How to obtain even origin from MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, events, browser, dom-events

I am trying to figure out which shadow DOM mutated an element on a web page (I have several shadow DOMs on a single page). I am using mutation observer for that. But I cannot find the origin/source of mutation. Though the target of mutation is always clear from the object.

```
let observer = new MutationObserver(mutationRecords => {
  console.log(mutationRecords); // console.log(the changes)
});
```

I was expecting that  MutationObserver has some property that would let me determine origin of mutation -- script name or html node in which the mutating script is located.
Yes - in my case the cause of mutation is script.

Comment: What would you expect this to return when the user clicks on a `<details>` element (and thus triggers an `open` attribute change?

Comment: user does not click anything, a script inside a shadow dom makes this mutation when it wants to make it. I want to be able to figure out Which of many shadow doms on the page did the mutation